# How to determine A?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Let $(\gamma, \tau)$ be an arc-length parametrized curve and $\mathcal A: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a Euclidean transformation so that the curve $\hat \gamma := \mathcal A\gamma$ satisfies $\hat \gamma(0)=0$ and $\hat \gamma'(0)= (1,0)$.

My question: How to determine $\mathcal A$ in terms of $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)$ now?

And what exactly is a Euclidean-transformation?

A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: The Euclidean transformations of $\Bbb R^2$ are the maps $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that preserve lengths. Any Euclidean transformation can be written as the composition of a rotation (or reflection through the origin) $B$, and a translation by some vector $\bf y$, and so can be written as
$${\bf x} \mapsto B {\bf x} + {\bf y}.$$

Comment: Now, just substitute your conditions to get constraints on $B$ and $\bf y$. (You'll see that there are exactly two solutions for any curve $\gamma$.)

Comment: Thank you, I  got the meaning of the Euclidean transformation I guess. It actually just moves the curve around/rotates it etc right? 
I am new to differential geometry, I didn't get what you meant by substituting my conditions to get constraints on B and y, sorry. Can you tell me what is meant by that?

Comment: @Travis : Are you including orientation-reversing isometries among what you call "rotations"? $\qquad$

Comment: Sure: We're looking for a Euclidean transformation $\mathcal A$ such that $(\hat\gamma)(0) = {\bf 0}$, or $\mathcal A(\gamma(0)) = {\bf 0}$. Substituting in our formula for a general Euclidean transformation from my first comment, we get $B(\gamma(0)) + {\bf y} = {\bf 0}$, and rearranging tells us what $\bf y$ has to be. Now, we can treat the other condition similarly to get a constraint on $B$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, this is what I mean by "rotation (or reflection through the origin)". As you hint, there's also an orientation-preserving version of this, where one only allows rotations, and in this case the conditions are enough to determine the (oriented) Euclidean transformation uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma(0)=:{\bf a}=(a_1,a_2)$ and $\gamma'(0)=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ (note that you have assumed $|\gamma'(\tau)|\equiv1$). The euclidean transformation ${\cal A}$ you are after is the composition of the translation $$T_{-{\bf a}}:\quad {\bf x}\mapsto{\bf x}-{\bf a}$$ with the rotation $R_{- \alpha}$ around ${\bf 0}$. The latter is given by the matrix
$$[R_{-\alpha}]=\left[\matrix{\cos\alpha&\sin\alpha\cr-\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\cr}\right]\ .$$ 
We now have to express ${\cal A}=R_{-\alpha}\circ T_{-{\bf a}}$ in terms of coordinates in order to obtain the explicit parametrization of $$\hat\gamma={\cal A}\circ\gamma=R_{-\alpha}\circ T_{-{\bf a}}\circ\gamma\ .$$ 
Obviously
$$T_{-{\bf a}}\circ\gamma(\tau)=\left[\matrix{\gamma_1(\tau)-a_1\cr \gamma_2(\tau)-a_2\cr}\right]\ ,$$
hence
$$\hat\gamma(\tau)=R_{-\alpha}\circ T_{-{\bf a}}\circ\gamma(\tau)=\left[\matrix{\cos\alpha&\sin\alpha\cr-\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\cr}\right]\>\left[\matrix{\gamma_1(\tau)-a_1\cr \gamma_2(\tau)-a_2\cr}\right]=\ldots\ .$$
On the RHS we don't obtain a $2\times2$-matrix, but a column vector, as it should be.